# Where does failed ABAP authorization check get logged?

Tags: abap

In ABAP I can conduct authorization checks using the command `AUTHORITY-CHECK`. In case the user has the required privileges, `sy-subrc` equals 0. Otherwise, it is unlike 0.

I wonder if such failed authorization checks are logged somewhere since this can be interesting in terms of application security.

I am aware of the notion of security audit log, system log and so forth. However, I never stumbled upon the fact that such authorization checks are put there.

Also, I know the transaction SU53, however, I believe it does not perform any long-term logging activity.

**Is there such a log that fetches all failed authorization checks?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you switch on the authority trace in ST01 or STAUTHTRACE, the attempts (whether failed or passed) are logged. However, that is intended for development and debugging purposes only. Permanently logging all auth checks of all users may not only be significant performance issue and generate a huge amount of data in short time, but it may also be illegal as it constitutes a permanent surveillance of the actions and performance of the employees.

Comment: I see you're based in Europe.  That certainly wouldn't be illegal in the states.  Though your other points should be an equally compelling argument against the practice.

Comment: @BryanCain Whether it is illegal depends on the circumstances - let's say that it can get you in a lot of trouble over here if abused, and it's usually a good idea to check whether what you're doing is compliant with the rules beforehand.